# Are SOAP Headers secure in WCF?

Tags: wcf

In WCF with transport mode security, when the SOAP headers are sent from client to server, are the SOAP headers encrypted in NetTcpBinding by default with windows credentials?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Transport security depends on the mechanism that the binding you have selected uses. For example, if you are using WSHttpBinding then the security mechanism is Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) (also the mechanism for the HTTPS protocol).If it is NetTcpBinding, the default is to use windows credentials for encryption. More information about transport in netTcpBinding, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/transport-of-nettcpbinding